# Raising a 2D array to a power in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I'm using C and have a 2D array representing a square matrix. What I want to do is to calculate the matrix to the power of `n`, a given integer.

I'm after the most efficient way to do this. My first thought was to multiply the matrix to itself `n` times but then I heard of exponentiation by squaring. However I'm not sure how to implement this, could someone please guide me through it?

Comment: If your problem is entirely related to logic, you can ask the same at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SouravGhosh algorithm questions are on-topic at both sites, but this question is specifically asking for implementation help which is on-topic at SO but off-topic at Programmers. Please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the basic outline:

```
Matrix matrixExponent(Matrix m, int n)
{
      Matrix accumulator = MatrixIdentity();
      Matrix power2 = m;

      while(n != 0)
      {
           if(n & 1)
                 accumulator = MatrixMultiply(&accumulator, &power2);
           power2 = MatrixMultiply(&power2, &power2);
           n = n / 2;
      }
      return accumulator;
}
```

You store an accumulator, which is the partially computed exponent. A given integer exponent can be broken down into a series of power-of-2 exponents multiplied together. For example when raising an array to the power of 14 (1110 in binary), the matrix multiplied by itself 14 times is equal to:

m<sup>14</sup> = m<sup>8</sup> * m<sup>4</sup> * m<sup>2</sup>

So you just compute all the powers of two by repeatedly multiplying power2 with itself, while stepping through each bit of the integer exponent n, and multiplying power2 with the accumulator each time the bit is a 1.

Comment: Nice answer, though I would change `Matrix.identity()` to `MatrixIdentity()` and `Matrix.multiply(x,y)` to `MatrixMultiply(&x,&y)`, because this is C, not C++.

Comment: MatrixIdentity would need the matrix to copy as a parameter: `MatrixIdentity(m)`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck MatrixIdentity() does not copy from or to the matrix m, so m is not needed as a parameter. It just returns a matrix with 1 on the diagonal and 0 everywhere else. BTW thanks for your earlier edit which fixed a bug in my code.

Comment: Duh (I wasn't thinking straight). You would still need size information, but that's probably outside the scope of a basic outline.